# Input value is not changed on Javascript

Tags: javascript

I make shopping Cart now with vanilla javascript, html, css.

This program is when consumer click selection tag, add new tag and change count.

To Add new Tag is already working. Change count is not work. When I clicked, selectA, selectB, selectC is changed but not working on input tag.

```js
var selectA = 0;
var selectB = 0;
var selectC = 0;

function handleOnChange(e) {
  // 선택된 데이터 가져오기
  let value = e.value;
  let name = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
  let itemList = document.getElementById("addItem");

  var Item = document.createElement('div');
  var itemName = document.createElement('div');
  var itemSumA = document.createElement('input');
  var itemSumB = document.createElement('input');
  var itemSumC = document.createElement('input');
  itemName.innerHTML = name;

  if (value === "A") {
    if (selectA === 0) {
      Item.appendChild(itemName);
      Item.appendChild(itemSumA);
      itemList.appendChild(Item);
    }
    itemSumA.value = selectA;
  } else if (value === "B") {
    console.log(selectB);
    if (selectB === 0) {
      Item.appendChild(itemName);
      Item.appendChild(itemSumB);
      itemList.appendChild(Item);
    }
    itemSumB.value = ++selectB;
  } else {
    if (selectC === 0) {
      Item.appendChild(itemName);
      Item.appendChild(itemSumC);
      itemList.appendChild(Item);
    }
    itemSumC.value = ++selectC;
  }

  document.getElementById("Sum").innerHTML = selectA * 39800 + selectB * 49800 + selectC * 59800;
}
```

```html
<li class="checked">
  <button class="accordion">주문 정보</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>상품 선택</p>
    <select name="tent" id="tent" onchange="handleOnChange(this)">
      <option value="A">A. 스피드 원터치 팝업텐트(3~4인용)</option>
      <option value="B">B. 5초 원터치 텐트(3인용) (+10,000)</option>
      <option value="C">C. 5초 원터치 텐트(5인용) (+20,000)</option>
    </select>
    <div id="addItem"></div>

  </div>
</li>
```

I want to know why.

Comment: Where is the `Sum` element in your HTML?

Comment: `itemSumA`, `itemSumB`, and `itemSumC` are all the same, why do you need 3 different inputs? You only append one of them, depending on the value of the select.

Comment: what is the form ID or name ? it is easier to use this relation notation !

Comment: First, Sum is under that html code. That form is under here... `<div id="myDIV" class="header"><h3>총 금액</h3><h1 id = "Sum"></h1></div>`

Comment: Second, item is just 3 things. A, B, C is that. I don't know how manage only one variable. So I make selectA,selectB,selectC.

Comment: Oh, I didn't use form...Thank you for your advice!

Comment: the use of forms allows to create a shorter code. I no longer do otherwise.